# What is the grid behind the map in an Android app developed with the ArcGIS SDK for Android?

Tags: android, arcgis

I am creating a simple mapping app using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android. I created a `MapView` and added a tile package (.tpk) to it as its base map. The picture below is how it appears on the screen. Can anyone tell me why there is a grid above and below my map and how to remove it? I thought it was the `MapView`'s grid so I tried calling `mapView.getGrid().setVisible(false)`, but the grid still appears.

[image: out put of my app on android device]

Comment: could you please tell me where you copied the `.tpk` file as when I am trying to get the tpk file from the sd card, it says the file is not found. Please help me bro.

Comment: i copied it in my SD card.so can u show me ur code so that i can tell u where u got it wrong

Comment: I'm using the same code that is in their samples..see the sample code [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/offline-routing/)..

Comment: try this                File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/ArcGIS");        System.out.println(file.exists());              if the result is true then you need to show me us code exactly because it should have worked indefinetly

Comment: Thankyou @Robel, the path given was wrong. And I corrected it. But I have one general doubt. I am trying to make an offline maps application. And thus I have disconnected internet connection from the device. Now, when I run the project, an  error saying `Unable to resolve host "server.arcgisonline.com": No address associated with hostname` occurs. Do I need an internet connection each time? then ehy is it called offline maps.. ;)

Comment: why would you need server.arcgisonline.com in ur code.and for u to develop an offline application u dont need to make ur internet connection off(or it doesnt matter if its off or on).

Comment: thats what i also dont understand. I was just adding the code in their samples and they dont have a call to `server.arcgisonline.com`.. i cant understand from where it is being called.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934594/offline-map-using-arcgis-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MapView.setMapBackground(int, int, float, float)](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html):

```
mapView.setMapBackground(Color.GRAY, Color.GRAY, 0, 0);
```

`MapView.getGrid()` is unrelated. If you call `mapView.getGrid().setType(GridType.MGRS)` and leave the grid's visibility at the default of `true`, you will see a Military Grid Reference System (MGRS) grid on top of the map.

Comment: S,u look like some one with some experience with arcgis, so can u help me with some additional questions.first one is is there a way i could make my map 3D in arc map,i know arc scene is for creating a 3D map but i need to convert my map into .tpk format for android and i can only do that from arcmap,so please if u know a way i could do that i will be very glad.and thanks for all ur previous assistants  and hopefully ur future assists to.

Comment: @RobelAlemu, 3D in ArcGIS Runtime for Android is probably coming later this year. TPKs will always be 2D though.

Comment: thanks.and if i am not asking to much can u tell me a better way to geocode a satellite image i got from google, I am using this link's steps to geocode but i am having some margin of error.                                      http://gis.yohman.com/up206a/how-tos/how-to-add-a-google-earth-satellite-image-into-arcmap/

Comment: thanks @Gary S..and if i am not asking to much can u tell me a better way to geocode a satellite image i got from google, I am using this link's steps to geocode but i am having some margin of error.                                      http://gis.yohman.com/up206a/how-tos/how-to-add-a-google-earth-satellite-image-into-arcmap/

Comment: so @Gary S. one more question,i calculated the error and figured out that if i could subtract/add my X and Y coordinate with some fixed value then i will get the correct coordinate on the map when i have a GPS fix.so do u know a way in which i could modify the drawing coordinate of LocationDisplayManager class?thanks in advance

Comment: @RobelAlemu, you should write new questions for those. That will get more people to see it and more likely to get you an answer. I don't know the answers off the top of my head.

Comment: can u take a look at this question please,http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146883/adding-barriers-is-not-working-in-arcgis-sdk-for-android

Comment: @GaryS. Could you please take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934594/offline-map-using-arcgis-android-sdk)