# Offline Map using ArcGIS android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, maps, arcgis

I'm trying to develop an Offline maps application using ArcGis android sdk. Followed the tutorials from the ArcGis website.Since it is an Offline Maps Applicaion, I am testing it without an internet connection. But, when I run the application,the `MapView` is blank. It just shows a black screen. When I checked the Logcat, It says

```
11-26 14:39:57.757 28520-28520/com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap D/GLSurfaceView: checkGLSurfaceViewlLogProperty get invalid command
11-26 14:39:57.839 28520-28548/com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap I/System.out: httpget:http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer?f=json
11-26 14:39:57.840 28520-28548/com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap I/System.out: http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer?f=json
11-26 14:39:57.846 28520-28548/com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap I/System.out: [CDS][DNS]Unable to resolve host "server.arcgisonline.com": No address associated with hostname
11-26 14:39:57.846 28520-28548/com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap E/ArcGIS: url =http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer
11-26 14:39:57.884 28520-28520/com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41ce4470 I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
11-26 14:39:57.891 28520-28520/com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{41d35928 com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap/com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41ce4470 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
```

I can't understand from where, a request to `server.arcgisonline.com` is going. My java file and xml file are as follows

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MapView mMapView;
    String extern = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    final String tpkPath = "/ArcGIS/samples/OfflineRouting/ImageryTPK.tpk";
    TiledLayer mTileLayer;
    GraphicsLayer mGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer(GraphicsLayer.RenderingMode.DYNAMIC);

    RouteTask mRouteTask = null;
    NAFeaturesAsFeature mStops = new NAFeaturesAsFeature();

    Locator mLocator = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTileLayer = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer(extern + tpkPath);
        // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

        // Set the tiled map service layer and add a graphics layer
        mMapView.addLayer(mTileLayer);
        mMapView.addLayer(mGraphicsLayer);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.esri.android.map.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        initExtent = "-1.3296373526814876E7 3930962.41823043 -1.2807176545789773E7 4201243.7502468005"
        mapoptions.MapType="Topo"
        mapoptions.ZoomLevel="16" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the **build.gradle** is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lalprakash.offlinearcgismap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        sourceSets.main{
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jni'
            jni.srcDirs=[]
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/arcgis-android-api.jar')
    compile files('libs/arcgis-android-app-toolkit.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-all-1.9.0.jar')
}
```

Also, I've placed the `tpk` file in the root of my internal memory. 
Please help me as I need it really badly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you remove the initextent and mapoption.maptype from ur XML and tell me what happens.i havent got the chance to take a look at ur stack trace but this should show u ur map on ur screen

Comment: Thankyou @Robel.. Now, the map is displayed. I have one more doubt..How will I show the place names along with the map that is being displayed.

Comment: i dont understand,do u want to lable the locations in the map?but take a look at the samples in the geocoding examples so that u will have some clue

Comment: What i meant is, I want the location names to be shown along with the maps like in other online maps.

Comment: then u have to do that in the tool where the map was developed initally(arc map).

Comment: is there any tutorial or something like that to do that..and will the location information be available in the tpk?

Comment: what u need to do is read about geocoding,georeferncing in the arcgis offical manual,and above all u need to read about how to use arc-map for developing maps because most of the things like routing and geocoding are done there.Geeting startd with it looks difficult but trust me its worth-yet.speccialy considering how much time and effort u will spend if u were developing using google-maps

Comment: yeah sure..I'll take a look at it..Anyway thanks for the help.. :)